# Spring mongotemplate query result with subDocuments

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

A document in `productChanges` collection looks like below.

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(9780876590034),
    "isbn" : NumberLong(9780876590034),
    "updDtime" : ISODate("2016-06-08T14:02:29.044Z"),
    "Audit" : {
        "LastProcCntrlNo" : 100192211,
        "UpdDtime" : ISODate("2016-06-08T14:02:29.044Z"),
        "AddDtime" : ISODate("2016-06-08T14:02:29.044Z")
    } 
}
```

I have my `ProductChanges.java` class

```
public class ProductChanges {
     Long isbn;
     Date updDtime;
     Audit audit;

     // getters & setters
}
```

I use `mongoTemplate` to query the DB, but I can't get `Audit` object populated.

```
// query the DB
List<ProductChanges> productChanges = mongoTemplate.find(query, ProductChanges.class, "productChanges");
```

This should be straightforward. Do I need to annotate my `Audit` object? Am I missing something trivial?

Spring Data MongoDB documentation was not helpful in finding an answer to this problem.

Comment: " I can't get Audit object populated": describe what is happening. Any error message? Is the list simple empty when it should not be?

Comment: @antoine-sac No error message. `productChanges` is populated with entries but `audit` is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Spring Data MongoDB documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-conventions):

> The short Java class name is mapped to the collection name in the following manner. The class `com.bigbank.SavingsAccount` maps to `savingsAccount` collection name.
>
> The fields of an object are used to convert to and from fields in the
>   document. Public JavaBean properties are not used.

Since your sub-document field is named `Audit` and the Java field name is `audit`, Spring Data couldn't populate the `audit` field as you expected.

In order to fix this problem, you either should rename your field to `Audit`:

```
public class ProductChanges {
     Long isbn;
     Date updDtime;
     Audit Audit; // renamed to Audit from audit

     // getters & setters    
}
```

Or Use `@Field` annotation:

```
public class ProductChanges {
     Long isbn;
     Date updDtime;
     @Field("Audit") Audit audit;

     // getters & setters
}
```

You can read more about mapping annotations [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.9.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations). And a word of advice, try to use a consistent naming convention.